# what wrong with this script sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table users with columns ID,USERSID
table :

```
  t_A(ID,usersID,ADATE,priceA,priceB)
  t_B(ID,usersID,BDATE,priceA,priceB)
  t_C(ID,usersID,CDATE,priceA,priceB)
```

I'm using this query to get SUM of price from 3 tables for X DATE , and USERSID

```
    declare @id int 
    set @id = 3 -- for example 

    SELECT SUM(priceA) as TA, SUM(priceB) as TB
    FROM  t_A,t_B,t_C
    WHERE  t_A.USERSID =  @id
    AND     t_B.USERSID =  @id
    AND     t_C.USERSID =  @id
    AND    ADATE >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate())) 
   AND     BDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate())) 
   AND    CDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()))
```

this script work only if the USERSID had a row in the three tables otherwise script return nothing

Comment: What do you mean it returns NULL? You have three columns in your SELECT statement. Does it return NULL for all of them? One of them? An error (which is what I would expect from the code above)?

Comment: You have a comma before your FROM which is incorrect

Comment: Also `priceC` doesn't appear to be a thing, based on your table structure.

Comment: will correct it, just miss typing ...

Comment: this script work only if the USERSID had a row in the three tables otherwise script return nothing

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if only one table has no USERID = 3 that result always will be empty. Workaround: use option with [UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator

```
DECLARE @id int 
SET @id = 3
SELECT SUM(x.priceA) as TA, SUM(x.priceB) AS TB
FROM (
      SELECT priceA, priceB
      FROM t_A 
      WHERE t_A.USERSID =  @id
        AND ADATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
      UNION ALL
      SELECT priceA, priceB
      FROM t_B 
      WHERE t_B.USERSID =  @id
        AND BDATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
      UNION ALL   
      SELECT priceA, priceB
      FROM t_C 
      WHERE t_C.USERSID =  @id
        AND CDATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
      ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a date column with a datediff.  Here are some things you could do:

```
AND ADATE >= GETDATE()
```

or:

```
AND DATEDIFF(d, ADATE, GETDATE()) > 1
```

You can check the syntax and [some examples at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. This way, it will return results as long as one of the tables satisfies the condition:

```
SELECT SUM(priceA) as TA, SUM(priceB) as TB, SUM(priceC) as TC
    FROM  t_A
    FULL JOIN t_B
    FULL JOIN t_C
    WHERE  t_A.USERSID =  @id
    AND     t_B.USERSID =  @id
    AND     t_C.USERSID =  @id
    AND    ADATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
   AND     BDATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
   AND    CDATE >= DATEDIFF(d,0,dateadd(d,0,getdate()))
```